# 404 when opening a localized page

Tags: localization, 404

I get a 404 page when I try to open an Italian page. Homepage `www.domain.com/it/` works, but when I proceed to `www.domain.com/it/assistenza-e-supporto` it gives me a 404.

English version works. Any idea where I should look to fix this?

I've followed the steps as desribed here: 
https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide

Config looks like this:

```php
return array(
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_US' => 'http://local.crafttraining.craft.dev/',
        'es' => 'http://local.crafttraining.craft.dev/es/',
        'it' => 'http://local.crafttraining.craft.dev/it/',
    ),
);
```

Update:
After a day of trying and searching I found out that once I remove the omitScriptNameInUrls from the general.php it works fine, but I would like to have nice url's.

.htaccess looks like this:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong. Thanks for helping me out with this.

Comment: You sure you've enabled Italian for section you're trying to view?

Comment: Hi Brad, yep, did that. The strange thing is that the italian homepage works perfectly on: http://local.crafttraining.craft.dev/it/. 

In this file I have 
`{% set pages = craft.entries.section('contentPages').level(1) %}.
 {% for page in pages %}
 <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
{% endfor %}`

This generates the links to the italian pages. Eg: http://local.crafttraining.craft.dev/it/assistenza-e-supporto.

Now, when I click that link, I get a 404 page. I checked the docs once more, but cannot find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does your server support PATH_INFO? http://buildwithcraft.com/help/enable-path-info

Comment: Hi Brad, your answer helpt me a littlebit further. This works:    'usePathInfo' => true,
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => false, so url's are with index.php: http://craft.dev/index.php/it/news-it/2015/we-just-installed-craft. If I set omitScriptNameInUrls to true it doesn't work anymore. 404's all over the place.

Comment: Do you have the correct RewriteBase in `it/.htaccess`? I think I saw that causing 404s somewhere.

Comment: This could be caused by a RewriteBase problem indeed, check this answer here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/25712/5948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it (at last). The thing was that the . before .htaccess was removed when copying the files to the /it/ folder on OSx